# Fixed Size to List

Tags: c#, collections

For declaration perspective the following is allowed

```
    IList<string> list= new string[3];
    list.Add("Apple");
    list.Add("Manago");
    list.Add("Grapes");
```

1)
It compiles fine,But runtime i am getting `"Collection was of fixed size"` error.
Ofcourse ,collection is  dynamically grown by size,why did such declaration is accepted by complier ?

2) What are the different lists that i can assign to IList ?
   Example

```
IList<string> fruits=new List<string>();
```

Here I am assigning List to IList ,What are the various collection 
   classes can i assign to IList?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The underlying problem here is that `System.Array` violates the substitution principle by implementing `IList<T>`.  A `System.Array` type has a fixed size which cannot be changed.  The Add method on `IList<T>` is intended to add a new element to the underlying collection and grow it's size by 1.  This is not possible for a `System.Array` and hence it throws.

What `System.Array` really wants to implement here is a read only style `IList<T>`.  Unfortunately no such type exists in the framework and hence it implements the next best thing: `IList<T>`.

As to the question about what types are assignable to `IList<T>`, there are actually quite a few including: `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` and `Collection<T>`.  The list is too long to put here.  The best way to see it all is to open `IList<T>` in reflector and look for derived types of `IList<T>`.

Comment: Dictionary<TKey, TValue> implements ICollection<T>, not IList<T>

Answer (score 6):

When you call list.Add, you are trying to insert an item to the end of you array.  Arrays are a fixed size collection so you can't do an Add.  Instead you will have to assign the entries via the indexer:

```
list[0] = "a";
list[1] = "b";
list[2] = "c";
```

Answer (score 2):

@Jake: Actually a string[] IS castable to an IList...   but you can't ADD to it.

If you want to pre-populate the list, then you *could* use something like:

```
IList<string> list= new string[3] { "Apple", "Mango", "Grapes" };
```

but then what's the point of making it an IList?  You still couldn't add to it.  If it really is a fixed-sized list, then make it a string[].  Otherwise, make it a List(), as Jake suggests.